# Selenium Webdriver Cannot find the element of the click button

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I don't know the element used to click the button.

I tried to write like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*/input[@type="button"]').click()
```

Error message:

> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message:
>   element not visible

HTML:

```
<input type="button" name="ctl00$c3$g_6_f947_400a_aa18_59efd84584ae$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RightRptControls$ctl00$ctl00$diidIOSaveItem" value="Save" onclick="if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;if (SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ2')) return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl33$g_69_f947_400a_aa18_59efd84584ae$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RightRptControls$ctl00$ctl00$diidIOSaveItem&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))" id="ctl00_ctl33_g_696_f947_400a_aa18_59efd84584ae_ct0_toolBarTbl_RightRptControls_ctl00_ctl00_diidIOSaveItem" accesskey="O" class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" target="_self">
```

Comment: <input type="button" name="ctl00$c3$g_6_f947_400a_aa18_59efd84584ae$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RightRptControls$ctl00$ctl00$diidIOSaveItem" value="Save" onclick="if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;if (SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ2')) return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl33$g_69_f947_400a_aa18_59efd84584ae$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RightRptControls$ctl00$ctl00$diidIOSaveItem&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))"

Comment: I want to click the "Save" button

Comment: First of all,please check path manually by inspect page -> Go to Tab "Element" then -> Ctrl+F -> Paste your path to check -> If it is found,it will highlight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the 'Save' word visible? if so you can try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Save')]").click()
```

Comment: Not to criticize the response, but it's always good idea to use the html tag in xpath. Also don't use contains, when you have a definite text. Just for understanding the downside, the same above xpath will click on any tag like Span with Save text. 

Here is the xpath that I would recommend as mentioned in my response `//input[@type='button' and @value='Save']`.

Comment: IMO, this won't work. OP's HTML resembles an `<input>` element which can't have _text_.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking for the value?

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*/input[@value="Save"]').click()
```

If this doesn't work it would be helpful if you could upload the HTML for the page you are testing or provide the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using `//*/input` rather using direct `//input`. Here is the solution.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='button' and @value='Save']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a dynamic element so to locate the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.ms-ButtonHeightWidth[value='Save'][name$='SaveItem']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='ms-ButtonHeightWidth' and @value='Save'][contains(@name, 'SaveItem')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```